# Extract non-const pointer from iterator in a const member function

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, reference

I was doing some programs on Object Oreinted Programming in C++.

Here is a brief skeleton of the situation

```
class coll;
class ele {
    private:
        int val;
        coll* p;

    public:
        ele(int v, coll* p);
        int value() const;
        friend bool operator==(const ele& El1, const ele& El2);
        friend bool operator<(const ele& El1, const ele& El2);
};
```

```
class coll {
    private:
        set<ele> data;
    public:
        ele* min() const {
            if(size()) {
                set<ele>::iterator minIt = min_element(data.begin(), data.end());
                ele* ptr = &(*minIt);
                return ptr;
            }
            return nullptr;
        }
};
```

In the `min()` function, the return type has to be non-const and the function has to be const compulsorily.

I don't know why, but min_element's iterator when de-referenced is giving a const reference. Like, `&(*minIt)` is a const pointer. But I need a non-const pointer to return.

What can be the reason for this behavior. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a `const` method all members are also `const` unless they're `mutable`. In addition `std::set` only has `const` iterators, you aren't allowed to modify elements of a set

Comment: @AlanBirtles The problem statement put constraints on this function, but not on the way the set had to be implemented. So, I guess stl set<> is not the most correct way to implement this class.

Comment: @AlanBirtles btw, since we are safe from modifications, I think some cast can do the work here.

Comment: Returning a non-const pointer to a member from a const method is just fundamentally wrong, go and find some better problems to solve

Comment: Agreed, this being compulsory is very odd. Is this from a programming course?

Comment: Look at [any stl reference returning function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) and you will see that `const` member functions return `const &` and non const member functions return `&`. Why are you even returning a pointer?